# modal window pop up in apex pageblockTable opens the same message for every record

Tags: record, popup, bootstrap, commandlink, modal

I have a pageBlockTable with modal pop up window opening on clicking a column value.  Example:  I have 2 columns Subject and Date.  When I click on ABC, in the modal pop-window I'm showing "XYZ and the corresponding date". Its working fine, but the problem is when I click on XYZ also, its showing the content of the first record (ABC details).

```
Subject Date
ABC     16/07/2015
XYZ     20/07/2015
```

Below is my VF code.  Please let me know what is the issue here.

Note: on the modal window close button also im reRedering the pageblockTable (coz some actions are done to the data on clicking subject, new data will reflect after I reRender)

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="urgentPT" >
      <apex:pageBlock>
        <div class="table-responsive vs3">
          <apex:pageBlockTable styleClass="table vs3" value="{!NotificationsList}" var="item">

            <apex:column headerValue="Message Subject">
              <apex:commandLink action="{!markAsRead}" html-data-backdrop="static" html-data-keyboard="false" html-data-toggle="modal" html-data-target="#dochelpUrgentPT" reRender="none" >
                <apex:outputText value="{!item.Subject__c}" />
              </apex:commandLink>

              <div id="dochelpUrgentPT" class="modal vs1 fade in">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <apex:commandLink styleClass="closebtn" html-data-dismiss="modal" rerender="webform,urgentPT" > <span class="fa-stack fa-lg "> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span> </apex:commandLink>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div class="h2 no-margin-t">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!item.Subject__c}"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="lead margin-b2">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!item.Body__c}"/>
                          </div>
                          <div><label>Date: </label>
                            <apex:outputText value=" {0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}">
                              <apex:param value="{!item.Email_Sent_At__c}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--  end row --> 
                    </div>
                    <!--  end modal body --> 
                  </div>
                  <!--  end modal content --> 
                </div>
                <!--  end modal dialog --> 
              </div>
              <!-- end modal -->                  
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Date">
              <apex:outputText value=" {0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}">
                <apex:param value="{!item.Email_Sent_At__c}"/>
              </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>

      </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </div>
      </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- APC PT URGENT END -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are using the same element ID "dochelpUrgentPT" for every row in your table. Use a unique ID for each row so the each link and popup are tied together by that unique ID e.g.:

```
<apex:commandLink ... html-data-target="#dochelpUrgentPT-{!item.Id}">
...
<div id="dochelpUrgentPT-{!item.Id}" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be rendering all that modal code for every row that is in the table. This could get pretty big and slow and could hit some limits.

I'd put the modal outside of your `pageblockTable` and call it from a click handler in your table cells. Your column:

```
<apex:column value="{!acct.acctId}" onclick="showModal('{!item.Subject__c}','{!item.Body__c}','{!item. Email_Sent_At__c}')"/>
```

The `showModal` function:

```
function showModal(subject,body,date){
    var subject = subject;
    var body = body;

    j$('#yourModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var modal = j$(this);
        modal.find('#modalSubject').text('Subject: ' + subject);
        modal.find('#modalBody').text('Body: ' + body);
    });

    j$('#yourModal').modal('show');
};
```

And your modal would be pretty much the same...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        ....etc
```

The only prob I see is that you don't get nice auto formatting of the date field. You can either format it in the controller and have it as a string or attempt to format it inside a VF binding - eg `{! ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  However i wasn't looking to use jquery here, just html tags.  And also data formatting is a must.  But for now, the other solution works for me.